# How to customize tineMCE H tags in Magento

Tags: javascript, tinymce, prototype, tinymce-3

For the CMS page editor in Magento,i would like to change the formatting of the H tags in the tinyMce editor. I would like something like for H1 tag, it is in red, bold, font:36px.

how would i go about to achieve this.

```
function init(){
    tinyMCE.init({
            style_formats:[
                {title:'h1', inline:'b', block:'h1', styles:{'font-size': '36px', 'font-family':'Arial','color':'#ff9900'}}
            ]
    });
}
document.observe('dom:loaded', init);
```

I tried the above, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css code to your `editor.css` (configuration parameter editor_css (`editor_css: '/path_to/editor.css'`))

```
h1 {
  'font-size': '36px',
  'font-family':'Arial',
  'color':'#ff9900'
}
```